# nested promises node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I read tutorial from [here](http://www.guru99.com/node-js-promise-generator-event.html) and I dont understand why second "insertOne" doesn`t work. Thanks for help!

```
var Promise=require('promise');
var MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB';
MongoClient.connect(url)
    .then(function(db) 
{
    db.collection('Documents').insertOne({
        Employeeid: 1,
        Employee_Name: "Petro"})
        .then(function(db1) {
            db1.collection('Documents').insertOne({
                Employeeid: 2,
                Employee_Name: "Petra"})
        })
        db.close();
    });
```

Comment: `db.close()` called before first `insertOne` resolved

Comment: Do not nest promises; this defeats the purpose of even using them.

Answer (score 3):

You have two asynchronous actions (db.insertOne) happening.

Therefore, you should have a `.then` after your second insertOne and close your connection

Code should look like this

```
{
    db.collection('Documents').insertOne({
        Employeeid: 1,
        Employee_Name: "Petro"})
        .then(function(db1) {
            db1.collection('Documents').insertOne({
                Employeeid: 2,
                Employee_Name: "Petra"})
        }).then(function(db2) {
              db.close();
        })
    });
```

Comment: It's not returning the promise from the second call to `insertOne`.

Answer (score 0):

See comments

```
MongoClient.connect(url)
    .then(function(db) {
        // you need a return statement here
        return db.collection('Documents').insertOne({
            Employeeid: 1,
            Employee_Name: "Petro"
        })
            .then(function(record) { 
                // another return statement
                // try db instead of db1
                return db.collection('Documents').insertOne({
                    Employeeid: 2,
                    Employee_Name: "Petra"
                })
            })
        .then(function() {
            // move the close here
            db.close();
        })

})
// Add an error handler
.then(null, function(error){
  console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: Strange, it doesn`t work. First record is apply, but second and db.close are not.

Comment: Are you sure its supposed to be `db1`? and not `db`? I think that's the issue. I've edited the code.